# How does this question have 2k views in spite of not being a HNQ?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[How can an independent researcher publish a well-written research paper / proof in a respected mathematical publication?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/201589/how-can-an-independent-researcher-publish-a-well-written-research-paper-proof)

I'm curious how this question has 2k views in spite of not being a HNQ & being only 2 days old. It seems very unusual - usually only HNQs reach 2k+ views this quickly. It's not the only one however, [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/198049/what-would-one-write-in-a-paper-describing-a-counterexample-to-a-published-proof) also reached 2k views in a few days without being a HNQ.

Comment: This question that I stumbled upon a few days ago has 12k views although being closed and having a negative score. I also felt that is quite a lot and was wondering how that happend, it seems much to high. It was closed after a day.

Comment: Not sure there will be a way for anyone here to answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated gives a more general look at what "views" means, or is supposed to mean.

Comment: Probably got linked somewhere, not sure how to figure out where though.